# mongodb : Can create new thread on FreeBSD?

Tags: mongodb, freebsd

We experienced some strange thing in our mongodb gridfs platform.
The platform actually is a bi Xeon E5 (bi quad core) with 128GB of memory, running on freebsd 9 with a zfs pool dedicated for mongodb.

```
[root@mongofile1 ~]# uname -sr
FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE


our /boot/loader.conf
vfs.zfs.arc_min="2048M"
vfs.zfs.arc_max="7680M"
vm.kmem_size_max="16G"
vm.kmem_size="12G"
vfs.zfs.prefetch_disable="1"
kern.ipc.nmbclusters="32768"


/etc/sysctl.conf

net.inet.tcp.msl=15000
net.inet.tcp.keepidle=300000
kern.ipc.nmbclusters=32768
kern.ipc.maxsockbuf=2097152
kern.ipc.somaxconn=8192
kern.maxfiles=65536
kern.maxfilesperproc=32768
net.inet.tcp.delayed_ack=0
net.inet.tcp.sendspace=65535
net.inet.udp.recvspace=65535
net.inet.udp.maxdgram=57344
net.local.stream.recvspace=65535
net.local.stream.sendspace=65535
```

we follow the recommandation for the ulimit :

```
[root@mongofile1 ~]# su - mongodb
$ ulimit -a
cpu time               (seconds, -t)  unlimited
file size           (512-blocks, -f)  unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d)  33554432
stack size              (kbytes, -s)  524288
core file size      (512-blocks, -c)  unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m)  unlimited
locked memory           (kbytes, -l)  unlimited
max user processes              (-u)  5547
open files                      (-n)  32768
virtual mem size        (kbytes, -v)  unlimited
swap limit              (kbytes, -w)  unlimited
sbsize                   (bytes, -b)  unlimited
pseudo-terminals                (-p)  unlimited
```

This server have a twin( same config exactly) for ReplSet in other datacenter and we have a virtualized arbiter.

Some time, almost 3 days, the process of mongodb exit
The problem begin with

```
Fri Nov  8 11:27:31.741 [conn774697] end connection 192.168.10.162:47963 (23 connections now open)
Fri Nov  8 11:27:31.770 [initandlisten] can't create new thread, closing connection
Fri Nov  8 11:27:31.771 [rsHealthPoll] replSet member mongofile2:27017 is now in state DOWN
Fri Nov  8 11:27:31.774 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.10.162:47968 #774702 (20 connections now open)
Fri Nov  8 11:27:31.774 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.10.161:28522 #774703 (21 connections now open)
Fri Nov  8 11:27:31.774 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.10.164:15406 #774704 (22 connections now open)
Fri Nov  8 11:27:31.774 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.10.163:25750 #774705 (23 connections now open)
Fri Nov  8 11:27:31.810 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.10.182:20779 #774706 (24 connections now open)
Fri Nov  8 11:27:31.855 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.10.161:28524 #774707 (25 connections now open)
Fri Nov  8 11:27:31.869 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.10.182:20786 #774708 (26 connections now open)
```

and after many "can create new thread"

```
[root@mongofile1 /usr/mongodb]# tail -n 15000 mongod.log.old |grep "create new thread"|wc
    5020   55220  421680
```

and finish by a magnificent

```
Fri Nov  8 11:30:22.333 [rsMgr] replSet warning caught unexpected exception in electSelf()
pure virtual method called
Fri Nov  8 11:30:22.333 Got signal: 6 (Abort trap: 6).
Fri Nov  8 11:30:22.337 Backtrace:
0x599efc 0x8035cb516
 0x599efc <_ZN5mongo10abruptQuitEi+988> at /usr/local/bin/mongod
 0x8035cb516 <_pthread_sigmask+918> at /lib/libthr.so.3
```

Extract of mongodb from top

```
78126 mongodb      77  20    0  1253G  1449M sbwait  0   0:20  0.00% mongod
```

If i restart the process when it crash, the problem is fixed for almost 3 days ;-) ( Windows Method is not the solution ...)

Do you already see that  ?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the error message says "[pure virtual method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Abstract_classes_and_pure_virtual_functions) called" would indicate that this is at least a bug in the mongodb code. The code that generates that message is [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/46bfd183986454ef9ccf5f333cb38be4ce4b1255/src/mongo/db/repl/consensus.cpp#L484), I think.